# Filling missing values for many variables from previous observation by group in SAS

Tags: arrays, macros, sas, retain

My dataset looks like this:

```
Date  ID Var1 Var2 ... Var5
200701 1  x    .    
200702 1  .    a
200703 1  .    .
200701 2  .    b 
200702 2  y    b
200703 2  y    .
200702 3  z    .
200703 3  .    .
```

I want my results to look like this:

```
Date  ID Var1 Var2 ... Var5
200701 1  x    .
200702 1  x    a
200703 1  x    a
200701 2  .    b 
200702 2  y    b
200703 2  y    b
200702 3  z    .
200703 3  z    .
```

I tried the following code below, but it didn't work. What's wrong with it?
Am I better off using array? If so, how?

```
%macro a(variable);
length _&variable $10.;
retain _&variable;
if first.ID then _&variable = '';
if &variable ne '' then _&variable=&variable;
else if &variable = '' then &variable=_&variable;
drop _&variable;
%mend;

data want;
set have;
%a(Var1)
%a(Var2)
%a(Var3)
%a(Var4)
%a(Var5)
run;
```

Appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full code works! Thanks

```
%macro a(variable);
length _&variable $10.;
retain _&variable;
if first.ID then _&variable = '';
if &variable ne '' then _&variable=&variable;
else if &variable = '' then &variable=_&variable;
drop _&variable;
%mend;

data want;
update have(obs=0) have;
by id;
output;
%a(Var1)
%a(Var2)
%a(Var3)
%a(Var4)
%a(Var5)
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UPDATE` statement can do that.  It is intended to process transactions against a master dataset so when the transaction value is missing the current value from the master table is left unchanged.  You can use your single dataset as both the master and the transaction data by adding `OBS=0` dataset option.  Normally it will expect to output only one observation per BY group, but if you add an `OUTPUT` statement you can have it output all of the observations.

```
data want;
  set have(obs=0) have ;
  by id;
  output;
run;
```